# Tensorflow matmul operation for rank>2 does not work

Tags: python, tensorflow, rank

I find the following on the Tensorflow documentation homepage for using the  matmul operation when rank>2:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/math_ops/matrix_math_functions#matmul

```
# 3-D tensor `a`
a = tf.constant(np.arange(1,13), shape=[2, 2, 3]) => [[[ 1.  2.  3.]
                                                   [ 4.  5.  6.]],
                                                  [[ 7.  8.  9.]
                                                   [10. 11. 12.]]]

# 3-D tensor `b`
b = tf.constant(np.arange(13,25), shape=[2, 3, 2]) => [[[13. 14.]
                                                    [15. 16.]
                                                    [17. 18.]],
                                                   [[19. 20.]
                                                    [21. 22.]
                                                    [23. 24.]]]
c = tf.matmul(a, b) => [[[ 94 100]
                     [229 244]],
                    [[508 532]
                     [697 730]]]
```

It simply isn't working when I plug it in Python. I get

```
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3
```

Anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with tensorflow so I don't know how much more a tensorflow array is compared to a numpy array, but you could try `numpy.dot` (but the order of dimensions might be different up there). Anyway, it's possible that your version of tensorflow is older than what the documentation corresponds to (assuming that the documentation is correct).

Answer (score 1):

Is your TensorFlow too old? Here's what I get in version 0.12rc0

```
a = tf.constant(np.arange(1,13).astype(np.float32), shape=[2, 2, 3])
b = tf.constant(np.arange(13,25).astype(np.float32), shape=[2, 3, 2])
sess.run(tf.matmul(a, b)) =>

array([[[  94.,  100.],
        [ 229.,  244.]],

       [[ 508.,  532.],
        [ 697.,  730.]]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Thank you but your code gives me the same error... Installed tensorflow just a couple of weeks ago, can I have gotten the wrong version? Do you know how I check which version I am currently running? Thanks

Comment: @user7318197 most modules support the `__version__` method, so try printing `tf.__version__`.

Comment: Okay thank you. I get "0.11.0" as answer. Seems like there is a release 0.12.0, so till try to install it and see if it helps.